# Launching LibreOffice Files - Unusual Window Behaviour

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu 11.10 Unity. If I launch LibreOffice Files (ODS, ODT, ODP) with a double click in their home folders they launch with the appropriate application (Calc, Writer, Impress) however the application windows do not display the usual Close, Minimize, Restore buttons in the left hand corner. There is just a blank space where they should be. In the Unity launcher on the left there is not the expected white arrow next to the launcher icon and the open app is not seen by the ALT+TAB keystroke when you have multiple windows open. For example: if you have an app open in this way and say Firefox, if you minimize Firefox you are only left with the desktop and you have no way to locate the open LibreOffice app. Clicking the app's icon in the launcher simply opens another instance. A messy workaround is to click [Firefox] to a restored window and the LibreOffice app can be seen behind it allowing a mouse click to bring it forward.

If I open the LibreOffice app from the launcher and then Open a file from its menu, it all behaves as expected. I don't find this as convenient; anyone know how to fix the bad behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This was not happening on my system until I tried to maximize the document window by using the mouse to slam the window against the top panel. Not knowing my own strength I ended up with the top of the window stuck under the top panel. I had to close the window using the file menu. Since then I got the same behaviour as you whenever I opened the document by a double click on the document file.

I found that the answer was to open and close the document a few times using the Launcher to load the program and then use the program's File Menu>Recent Documents to open the document. The first time I tried this the maximized document showed the same behavior as you described. It was only after repeating this a few times that the document's window behaviour went back to normal.

It is also useful to know that a double click on a window's top panel will maximize the window and that a double click on the desktop's top panel will minimize a window. In case it happens again.

I have tried to repeat this experiment but I have been unable to.

Regards.